# How to run laravel5.6 applicationin phpdesktop app with SQLite Database

Tags: laravel-5.6, phpdesktop

I am using `Laravel 5.6` application with `SQLite` database. It is well running on `XAMPP` server but I want to use it on `PHPDesktop` App. when I keep all file on `PHPDesktop` App "WWW" derectory and run the `phpdesktop-chrome.exe` file the the given error is displaying.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in C:\Users\AN\Desktop\phpdeskto\www\core\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php on line 242
```

Comment: This is a PHP error. Laravel is not compatible with given PHP version embedded in phpdesktop. You can replace PHP version in phpdesktop with one that is compatible with Laravel 5.6, see Knowledge Base wiki page for instructions.

Comment: **@CzarekTomczak**  i have change PHP Desktop App PHP Verson now using 7.1.3, And now the login page is coming but after inputing email and password pag redirection is not working . **Error 404: Not Found,
File not found**  this error is displaying.

Comment: You have to configure routing, see https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/PHP-frameworks-support#laravel

Comment: Many many Thanks **@Czarek Tomczak **  my one dream have successes. is it possible to set back button or forward button as like any browser or microsoft product. and how to change php default elephant icon after compiling exe file by Inno setup.

Comment: You can implement Back/Forward buttons via html/js UI. Create a button and call `history.back()` or `history.forward()`. Or create a custom mouse context menu via js. For icon see https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Settings#icon

Comment: **@Czarek Tomczak** i am faceing another problem with sqlite database connection. database location is "www/database/database." i have changed  "www/configue/database.php" as like **..'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlite'),..  'database' => env('DB_DATABASE',.... database_path('database.sqlite')),my problem is that when i give  pc root path in **.env** file then no problem as like "C:\Users/.......database.sqlite "  when  "DB_DATABASE=database.sqlite" then show "database.sqlite) does not exist" my question is that what is real database path and database connection system.in laravel 5.6